# Nivo Slider images are rotating slowly and out of sync in IE8

Tags: sharepoint-designer

We are using the Nivo Slider with a publishing site in SP2010. We have three images and in all the browsers except IE7 & 8. In those browsers the images rotate in extremely slow or (it seems) not at all. The dots cycle through out of sync with the images also. We are using jQuery-1.4.2. The site is https://communityservice.wustl.edu/ 
Any help would be appreciated. 
Thank you!
djlender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you been testing the Nivo outside of SharePoint previously (via HTML page)?? Both  IE 7 and IE 8 are not considered "modern" browsers, on contrary, and they support quite badly transitions/sliding and of course fading, down to nothing! Also, not sure if you checked, but it seems that Nivo slider has an issue with IE 7 described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558920/nivo-slider-not-working-with-ie7

Most important seems to be an issue with Nivo performance due to a meta "X-UA-Compatible" that indeed exists in SharePoint master page for backward compatibility fallback.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8"/>
```

That could be changed (see here http://support.bind.pt/entries/20485257-Known-issues-with-Internet-Explorer-under-SharePoint-2010) but particularly for Publishing pages we've experiencing issues particularly while manipulating Ribbon (options explained http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/expression/dd835379.aspx)

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

or

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

After a short analysis of the home page already I would suggest lighten up the page (1.1Mb profile) - as general concepts:

1. Ribbon related scripts are loaded even for Anonymous users
2. Publishing pages are coming with lots of CSS not really used  -remove those from Master and Page layouts
3. Better leverage the caching (proxy/page)
4. Integrate the latest library (if possible for your other scripts)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. We've been trying all of these suggestions but nothing seems to be working. the slide show does work but just very slowly and disjointed. So I get the feeling it's a compatibility thing somewhere. Just can't pinpoint it. I've tried the "X-UA-Compatible" stuff with no luck. I downloaded the Nivo Slider from their site and it seems to run in IE8 but without the transitions. But it at least works.